# docker remove containers by image

Tags: docker

I need the smallest code possible to remove all containers that were run from a specific image. For example, to run the container:

```
docker run -p 8888:80 fakeuser/my-image-name
```

And to remove the container (or containers):

```
docker rm -f "all containers that were run from the image fakeuser/my-image-name"
```

Is this possible? If so, whats the syntax? A one liner would be great if possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does https://linuxconfig.org/remove-all-containners-based-on-docker-image-name work for you?  `docker ps -a | awk '{ print $1,$2 }' | grep fakeuser/my-image-name | awk '{print $1 }' | xargs -I {} docker rm {}`

Comment: yes it does - many thanks - a bit gung ho as I expected an answer would use docker inspect - but my scripts not a work of art so this will do :D if you add an answer I will accept - had to add docker rm -f to get it to work btw but no great genius there